# Do finite sized 1D Hamiltonians have free energies which are analytic everywhere in the complex plane?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, partition-function, analyticity

It's well known that 1D classical and quantum short-ranged Hamiltonians have free energies which are analytic/holomorphic everywhere as a function of inverse temperature $\beta=1/k_BT$ (see Araki, "Gibbs states of a one dimensional quantum lattice"). As a result we know  the free energy has no poles anywhere in the complex plane and have no thermal phase transitions.

However, if we considered a 1D *finite* sized system on $N$ particles, is it true that the free energy per particle is still holomorphic in $\beta$ everywhere, or do poles exist? Are any results known about this? Does the result potentially depend on the boundary conditions, or whether the system is translationally invariant?

Comment: It is hard to imagine how a finite sum of the form $\sum e^{-\beta E}$ could have any singularities (other than $\beta=\infty$). It is a sum of entire functions, hence entire. I guess you have something else in mind? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform : He's talking about the free energy, not the partition function, so you have to take the logarithm. This induces singularities since the partition function can vanish (usually infinitely often) for complex values of $\beta$ (in many simple Ising-like cases, the partition function is a polynomial in $e^{\beta}$ or some other smooth function of $\beta$). I don't think that the free energy of any nontrivial model is actually analytic in the *whole* complex plane. Of course, there may be no singularities in a neighborhood of the real axis.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform : Note also that finding regions in which the partition function does not vanish (and hence in which the free energy is analytic) is the crucial point in the Lee-Yang theory.

Comment: @YvanVelenik : when you say "I don't think that the free energy of any nontrivial model is actually analytic in the whole complex plane", have I misinterpreted the paper I quoted by Araki? Also the paper "General Non-Existence Theorem for Phase Transitions
in One-Dimensional Systems with Short Range Interactions" also seems to indicate the free energy can be analytic in the whole plane for 1D classical models. 

Or were you talking specifically about finite sized 1D lattices in that comment?

Comment: @YvanVelenik : just to add, a region without zeros around the real axis might be sufficient for my purposes, provided it does not decrease as the system size increases (i.e. it has width O(1) with as N -> infinity).

Comment: Consider the simplest model: a collection of $N$ noninteracting spins $\sigma_i\in\{\pm 1\}$ with Hamiltonian $H=\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i$. Then the partition function is $Z_N=(2\cosh\beta)^N$. Obviously $\cosh\beta=0$ when $\beta=i(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi)$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, so that the free energy cannot be well defined (let alone analytic) there. Note that the size $N$ is totally irrelevant in this case, so that the conclusion is the same in the thermodynamic limit. So, you probably misunderstand the statement of the paper (I haven't read it). My guess is that he speaks about *real* analyticity.

Comment: I am not familiar with the available results for quantum spin chains, but an analogous results to what you want in the classical case is Theorem 5.6.2 in Ruelle's *Statistical Mechanics, Rigorous Results*, which indeed establishes real analyticity of the free energy for one-dimensional systems with finite-range interactions (extensions exist to interactions of infinite range, for instance in papers by Ruelle and by Dobrushin).

Comment: Note also that real analyticity implies analyticity in an open neighborhood of the real line in the complex plane, which may be what you need.

Comment: In the paper by Araki you refer to, just after his Theorem 2.1, he states *"The holomorphy in $\Phi$ means the **real** holomorphy in $\zeta= (\zeta_1,\dots,\zeta_n)$ when [...]"*. Moreover, he states right at the beginning of the paper that his paper is a quantum analogue of Ruelle's result. So, I think that it is fair to say that he is talking of real analyticity here.

Comment: @YvanVelenik : thank you for correcting my misunderstanding! Do you know of any results about the "width" of the neighbourhood around the real line for which there are no zeros, either for finite or infinite 1D systems? 

For example, if there is no partition function zero within width "w" either side of the real line in the thermodynamic limit, can there be zeros within this region for 1D finite systems?

Comment: "Note also that real analyticity implies analyticity in an open neighborhood of the real line in the complex plane, which may be what you need." -- this may work for my purposes proved that there is a constant sized region around the real line which remains zero free as system size N goes to infinity.

Comment: By the way, I checked out your stat phys textbook. It is excellent! Thank you for making it available online!

Comment: I don't know (at least, it does not come to my mind right now) a result of the type you'd like. I'll think about it. However, it seems highly likely to me that the arguments used to prove the result for infinite 1d systems should yield an analogous statement for finite systems. I haven't checked, though. I am happy that you like the book ;) .